# Fetch values from Struct of Array of Struct

Tags: coldfusion

I need to fetch a value from an Array of Structures. In the object below, I want to fetch the `value` column of the struct, which is nested inside the array of struct. I think I can use `structFindValue`, but am not sure.

Here is the screenshot for this:

[image: Struct of Array of Structs]

What I have tried is this:

```
<cfdump var=#StructFindValue(emails,"value","all")# />
```

Please guide me how can I find the `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found it like this, not a good way but working, as of now, i ned only 1 array:

```
<cfset result = getEmailAddr.emails[1].value>
```

Comment: well, i the array lkist continues like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.. The ni think i will need some kind of good custom function to fetch the values, just a thought, not sure about it

Comment: You can loop through your array like this `<cfloop array="#getEmailAddr.email#" index="email"><cfdump var="#email.value#"></cfloop>`